# Import personal java classes intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ to study Java, and I'd like to know how to import classes that I create myself. For example, I have a main folder called Projects, and in this folder, I have two other folders, one called Queue and another called List. How do I use the Queue.java class in the List directory? Do I need to import it in some way?

```java
public class Queue {
    private Node start;

    public Queue(){
        start = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return start == null;
    }

    public void enqueue(int element) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            Node newNode = new Node(element);
            newNode.next = start;
            start = newNode;
        } else {
            Node current = start;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = new Node(element);
        }
    }

    public int dequeue() {
        int result = -1;

        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("Error: The queue is empty");
        } else {
            result = start.data;
            start = start.next;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void display() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("Error: The queue is empty");
        } else {
            Node current = start;
            System.out.print("\nQueue ");
            while (current != null) {
                System.out.printf("|%d|", current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not be declaring classes in the default package.  It makes them next to impossible to reuse.  And since that is the whole point here, you've just defeated yourself.  You can't import a class from the default package!  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html for ideas / conventions on naming the package.  I'm aware that you probably don't intend to share or publish these classes, but it is a good idea understand the right way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I advise against naming your classes Queue and List because those are classes built into the JDK and so it will conflict or be confusing whether that's your class or the one made by Java. You can call them StyodQueue and StyodList instead.

When you type a class you haven't yet imported, the class name will be red but underlined and if you click it and press alt + enter, IntelliJ will ask you which class you'd like to import in order to make it usable.

[image: import]

[image: import1.5]

[image: import2]

Then IntelliJ will automatically add the corresponding import statement to the top of your file like so:

```java
import java.awt.List;
```

[image: import statement]

If there aren't multiple choices for that class because the class name is unique, then alt enter will automatically generate an import statement.

Comment: There is no "imports" option in IntelliJ, only something like "add dependency." I don't know how to revert this action. I would like to just type "import" because when I select "add dependency," instantiating the classes works fine, but there is no import at the beginning of the code.

Comment: That’s because the classes you want to use should be in the same project, just different folders. Otherwise your projects are libraries and you must builld a jar and reference it in your main project. Instead of having separate projects for your queue and list, make a single project called StyodLibrary for these classes.